# Update entity with OneToMany relationship with JPA/Spring

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've been researching this for a while and still couldn't find a satisfactory answer for my problem.

I have an entity on my postgres DB (product) that has a ManyToOne relationship with another entity (Dun).

Each product may have N duns.

On my PUT endpoint, the desired behavior would be:
Every time I update a product, it replaces all the duns with the ones provided on the endpoint.

Is there any way to handle it automatically by Hibernate/JPA?

In order to make it easier to test and explain the issue, I've uploaded a project on Github on the following link https://github.com/brunapereira/jpaexample

If there's no way to handle it automatically by JPA, what's the best way to solve it with code?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to remove Duns by product id, then get the product by id, add the new duns then save back.